# Заполнение датафрейма через цикл

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Встала такая задача: заполнить df через цикл на основании значения переменной i. То есть, получить что-то подобное:

|  | test1 | test2 | wq |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 30 | 40 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 40 | 40 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 50 | 40 |  |
| 3 | 4 | 60 | 40 |  |
| 4 | 5 | 70 | 40 |  |
| 5 | 6 | 80 | 40 |  |
| 6 | 7 | 90 | 40 |  |
| 7 | 8 | 100 | 40 |  |
| 8 | 9 | 110 | 40 |  |

А хотелось бы получать что-то такое:

|  | test1 | test2 | wq |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 30 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 40 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 50 | 10 |  |
| 3 | 4 | 60 | 15 |  |
| 4 | 5 | 70 | 20 |  |
| 5 | 6 | 80 | 25 |  |
| 6 | 7 | 90 | 30 |  |
| 7 | 8 | 100 | 35 |  |
| 8 | 9 | 110 | 40 |  |

Сам код такой получился:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'test2': [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110]})
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['wq'] = i*5
    
display(df)
```

Пробовал писать `df['wq',i] =...` -  просто насоздавалось много столбцов с обозначениями wq,1  wq,2 и т.д.

Хотелось бы узнать, как это сделать через цикл? Если есть какой-то другой подход — тоже интересно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы получили такой результат, потому что вы на каждой итерации цикла заполняете **весь** столбец одним значением, перезаписывая все значения в столбце. Правильно заполнить столбец в цикле можно так:

```
df["wq"] = -1
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'wq'] = i*5
```

---

Но лучше всегда использовать **векторные** методы вместо циклов:

```
import numpy as np

df["wq"] = np.arange(0, 5 * len(df), 5)
```

или

```
df["wq"] = range(0, 5 * len(df), 5)
```

результат:

```
In [359]: df
Out[359]:
   test1  test2  wq
0      1     30   0
1      2     40   5
2      3     50  10
3      4     60  15
4      5     70  20
5      6     80  25
6      7     90  30
7      8    100  35
8      9    110  40
```

Comment: 'df["wq"] = -1
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'wq'] = i*5 '

Такая же петрушка . Везде -1 заполняется

Comment: @convair35, что-то вы недоговариваете - после выполнения цикла в столбце "wq" будут правильные значения

Comment: да - действительно. Не туда смотрел. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Зачем все эти сложности, просто умножаете индекс на 5:

```
df['wq'] = df.index * 5
```

Comment: я тоже об этом подумал вначале, но что если значения индекса отличаются от [0,1,2,...] ?

Comment: df["wq"] = -1
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'wq'] = i*5

Не могу оформить как код. Уже все перепробовал...

Он по этому коду везде вписывает -1

Comment: @MaxU Ну это да. Кто знает, какие данные в реальности